# What is the AST for decorator in typescript?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-compiler-api

I need to know what is the AST name of the typescript decorators?

I need it for the ESLint [selectors](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/selectors).

I saw a tool somewhere but I can't find it

Comment: Maybe https://astexplorer.net/ could be useful here?

Comment: This is what i need. So the selector is `Decorator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorators are available on the modifiers of the decoratable node. There is a `ts.getDecorators` helper method you can use to access them though:

```
const classDecl: ts.ClassDeclaration = ...;
const decorators = ts.getDecorators(classDecl);
// use decorators here
```

This is the type of `ts.Decorator`:

```
export interface Decorator extends Node {
    readonly kind: SyntaxKind.Decorator;
    readonly parent: NamedDeclaration;
    readonly expression: LeftHandSideExpression;
}
```

https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/AIZQ9gtgpgIlDGYBOBDALsgUPANigzvgAQCiAHihAA45REDemAvkA